# Django Static file wont load in Block Content even when {% load static %} is applied

Tags: javascript, python, django

I can't load my static particles.js file inside my block content even when I have load static in my file.

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}

```
    <!--Particles-->
        <script src="{% static 'particles/particles.js' %}" defer="defer"></script>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/particles.js@2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
```

In chrome I am getting this error

GET http://localhost:8000/static/particles/particles.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Although it is pointing to the right place.

[Settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBy7R.png)
[file with particles.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwS84.png)

Comment: The tag `load static` is working as expected. However, you file is not found `404 (Not Found)`. Can you provide your settings.py file to check `STATIC_*` constantes? Does your file exist in the folder `/static/particles/'?

Comment: Pretty sure it is something to do with settings.py. I added screenshots. The file does exist.

Comment: Is ` django.contrib.staticfiles` set in `INSTALLED_APPS`? Also, try to change `STATICFILES_DIRS` to this `[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]`

Comment: Thanks Vincent, I was actually putting the particles folder that has my JS file in the root static instead of the app 'ticker' static folder that I had declared in my settings.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually putting the particles folder that has my JS file in the root static instead of the app 'ticker' static folder that I had declared in my settings.py.